# DevExpress XAF - How to open a detail view in a new browser window/tab

Tags: devexpress, xaf

This SHOULD be a fairly easy thing to do... Say you have a standard XAF BO list view and detail view. In the web UI, when you click on the row in the list view of the BO, it opens the detail view of the BO in display-only mode in the same browser window. Same thing if you click on the Edit icon in a list view row, it opens the detail view of the BO in edit mode in the same browser window.

I would like for the detail view of the BO to come up in another browser tab. Is there an easy way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported out of the box, but you can workaround using cookieless sessions at your own risk. Read more: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S19224

Comment: Wow. After reviewing the S19224 ticket, I gotta say, this is a pretty sad state of affairs. But thanks for the info, Erik.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently (after reviewing the support ticket S19224), there isn't an easy way to do this. This is a real shortcoming of the XAF web UI.

Comment: XAF is a framework. You'll have a hard time if you try to fight the framework too much. Yes, some simple things are difficult with XAF. But a lot of difficult things are simple: security, reporting, charting, model, workflow, etc.

Comment: While I appreciate the sentiment of your comment, having a web application in which one can have multiple browser windows open to the same application should not be an example of "fighting a framework". IOW, Any framework which purports to generate a web application for you that generates one in which you can't have multiple web browser windows open on that application, is a pretty lacking framework. But that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Now, the feature is supported out of the box since 16.2

Thanks

Comment: Could you give a link to a source? Or any kind of documentation on this?

Comment: Same comment as Thomas W. How exactly does this work now?